# Retrieve values in each cluster in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have successfully run the DBSCAN algorithm (here is the stripped down command):

```
results <- dbscan(data,MinPts=15, eps=0.01)
```

and plotted my clusters:

```
plot(results, data)
```

`results$cluster` returns a list with numeric values. The value at each index reflects the cluster to which the original data in that index belongs:

```
[1] 0 1 2 1 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 1 2 0 2 2 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
[52] 0 2 2 0 0 1 2 2 0 2 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 1 0 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
[103] 2 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 2 1 1 0 1 2 1 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 0 2 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 1
```

However, how can I retrieve the values of the original data that is in each cluster? For example, how can I get all the values from the original data that are in cluster #2?

Comment: `data[results$cluster==2]` or `data[results$cluster==2,]`, I think.

Comment: @Frank--Thanks! It's the latter. If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this should do the trick for, e.g., cluster #2:

```
data[results$cluster==2,]
```